# singularity pulls but does not search lolcow?

Tags: singularity-container

`singularity search lolcow` gives me: FATAL:   Couldn't search library: request did not succeed: http status code: 504

However `singularity run library://lolcow` works and `singularity search tensorflow` does too.

Am I doing something wrong or not doing something or what?? I did not mention that tensorflow containers are in `library://...`